Pushups with weak core
What are the problems occur, if do pushups with weak core ? Does it put stress on joints around pelvis or injure them?

Doing too many push-ups with a weak core will inevitably lead to having a strong core. There is a very real danger of getting stronger when exercising, so if you don’t want to get stronger, exercise should be avoided at all costs.
Joking aside, there is no tangible risk of injury to your hips or back doing push-ups. As long as your selected posture is comfortable and not acutely painful, there is nothing to worry about, and over time, your core muscles will get stronger.

Generally, the injury risk from a weak core is in dynamic situations: Since the body can only slowly and/or inadequately react to pertubations of the system, significant forces are reaching the passive structures in injury-prone angles.
In isometric situations, this risk is virtually non-existent. On the other hand, senso-motoric training would be much better to train your core functionally. Yet, you'll need a (good) coach for that, so starting with something is definitely better than nothing.
